# How to return CDATA section from a Web API

Tags: xml, vb.net, api, rest, cdata

Using vb.net a Web API will return the XML in the same structure of a defined class:

```
Public Class Human
   Public Property Name As String = ""
   Public Property Height As String = ""
   Public Property Age As String = ""
   Public Property Sex As String = ""
End Class
```

So the API would return the type Human and would give results like this because the class defines the xml structure:

```
<Human>
   <Name>Bill</Name>
   <Height>129cm</Height>
   <Age>32</Age>
   <Sex>Male</Sex>
</Human>
```

Is it possible to return a CDATA section in the same way?

I've tried declaring one the of the Properties in the Class as:

```
Public Class Human
   Public Property Name As String = ""
   Public Property Height As String = ""
   Public Property Age As String = ""
   Public Property Sex As String = ""
   Public Property Details As System.Xml.Linq.XCData
End Class
```

and then trying to populate it like this:

```
Dim Result As New Human

Result.Details = New System.Xml.Linq.XCData("text here")
```

But when I call the operation I get no data back, so I figure I'm doing something very wrong here.

I've also tried setting the data this way:

```
Dim temp As System.Xml.Linq.XCData = <![CDATA[text here]]>
Result.Details = temp
```

Comment: Any possibility you could tell us why you want CDATA rather than just a properly escaped text node?

Comment: We'd like to be able to maintain any formatting of data added to that field, even if it contains tags or script

Comment: You need to create your own custom Xml serializer which will add `CDATA`. But why you cannot use `JSON` for this purpose?

Comment: We want to be able to offer both XML and JSON responses, as we can control that with  `WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.Format`.  I figured I'd need to create a custom Xml Serializer but was hoping there might be away to avoid that.

Comment: Could you use Get/Set for the Details property?